# array of points with OpenGL Android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, multidimensional-array, point

im trying to make an array of points in a grid like fashion but one point just shows up in the middle :I

```
private Point[][] sq = new Point[10][10];

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {



    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    for(int x = 0; x< 10 ; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y< 10 ; y++){
            sq[x][y] = new Point(x/10,y/10);
            gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, x/10,-5.0f);
             sq[x][y].draw(gl, 0, 1, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming openGL ES is the same as standard openGL you need to push and pop the matrix each time you transalte. Else you are going to translate by 0 the first time then by 0.1 and then 0.3 and then 0.6 etc...

But I assume you want to translate by 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 etc...

I'm also unsure why you are only translating along the y axis with the x value? I think this:

```
gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, x/10,-5.0f);
```

should be this:

```
gl.glTranslatef(x/10.0f, y/10.0f, -5.0f);
```

I think you want something like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x< 10 ; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y< 10 ; y++){

        sq[x][y] = new Point(x/10.0f, y/10.0f);

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glTranslatef(x/10.0f, y/10.0f, -5.0f);
        sq[x][y].draw(gl, 0, 1, 0);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct - in Ryans sample code, each Translate effects the last. You must restore the matrix state.

Comment: thank you, it worked! i was only translating the y axis just to see if it was actually displaying them... and i was really tired

Comment: Awesome, you should accept this as the answer then :) I also think it would be worth using the suggestions that didierc has given.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `gl.glVertex2f` to draw your vertices, and store the coordinates in an array:

```
float [] coords = new float[200];
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        coords[(x * 10 + y) * 2] = (float)x/10.0f;
        coords[(x * 10 + y) * 2 + 1] = (float)y/10.0f;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    gl.glVertex2f(coords[i * 2], coords[i * 2 + 1]);
```

If you want to draw a regular grid, given vertices with absolute coordinates, you don't need to use `gl.glTranslate`.

Finally, you can avoid rebuilding the array of points each time you do a render: just build the array once - say in the constructor for now, and only loop on the array for drawing in the `onDrawFrame` method. I don't know what your plan is later on though, but if the array size doesn't change, you will gain some performance by always using the same, even if you need to move the points.

As an exercise, I suggest creating a class to wrap the coordinates array and provide a few simple operations on the array. This could serve as a good introduction to the vertex array and buffer features supported by OpenGL.